# Is there a better way to access Supabase generated TS types?

Tags: typescript, types, supabase, supabase-js

I have created a table called `customer` in my supabase db.
Generated my types using

```
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id "$PROJECT_REF" --schema public > types/supabase.ts
```

In my React app this is how I am referencing the generated types.

```
const [customerDetails, setCustomerDetails] = useState<Database["public"]["Tables"]["customer"]["Row"]>()
```

Can it be a bit more cleaner, like this?

```
const [customerDetails, setCustomerDetails] = useState<customer>()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this

https://github.com/FroggyPanda/better-supabase-types

to post-process the types that supabase generates. That will generate a new schema file with content like this

```
export type Account = Database['public']['Tables']['accounts']['Row'];
export type InsertAccount = Database['public']['Tables']['accounts']['Insert'];
export type UpdateAccount = Database['public']['Tables']['accounts']['Update'];
```

If you don't want another dependency or write your own post-processor script, you could also improve the types with some helper types as suggested [here](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/13364#discussioncomment-6042221):

```
export type Row<T extends keyof Database['public']['Tables']> = Database['public']['Tables'][T]['Row'];
export type InsertDto<T extends keyof Database['public']['Tables']> = Database['public']['Tables'][T]['Insert'];
export type UpdateDto<T extends keyof Database['public']['Tables']> = Database['public']['Tables'][T]['Update'];
```

Which will lead to

```
import { InsertDto, Row, UpdateDto } from '@src/interfaces/database';

export type Location = Row<'location'>;
export type LocationInsertDto = InsertDto<'location'>;
export type LocationUpdateDto = UpdateDto<'location'>;
```